# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).raty is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, raty

I got this error in the view whhen I call Raty

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).raty is not a function
```

[Chrome Console Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tESg4.jpg)

I think I fail to load the js file or there is some sort of conflict?

I put the [copy/paste raty code](https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty/blob/master/lib/jquery.raty.js) in:

```
app\javascript\packs\jquery.raty.js
```

and I call raty in a module this:

```
<div id="stars"></div>
```

script in my view:

```
<script>
  $('#stars_<%= reservation.id %>').raty({
    path: '/javascript/packs',
    scoreName: 'guest_review[star]',
    score: 1
  });
</script>
```

my application.js

```
import 'bootstrap'
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
require("jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker")
import JQuery from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.JQuery = JQuery;
import toastr from 'toastr';
global.toastr = require("toastr");
toastr.options.closeButton = true;
```

Thank you!

---

SOLVED: require the raty.js in the application.js file

```
require("packs/jquery.raty")
```